# How to get last activity of user from ejabberd?

Tags: ejabberd

I try to get the last_activity of user using ejabberd API `get_last` but getting this error: `REST API Error: get_last([{<<"user">>,<<"67456efc-be57-4cbd-a176-527de2dce19d@faiqkhan-virtualbox">>},{<<"host">>,<<"faiqkhan-VirtualBox">>}]) -> error:{module_not_loaded,mod_last,<<"faiqkhan-VirtualBox">>} [{gen_mod,get_module_opts,2,[{file,"src/gen_mod.erl"},{line,338}]},{gen_mod,get_module_opt,3,[{file,"src/gen_mod.erl"},{line,318}]},{gen_mod,db_mod,3,[{file,"src/gen_mod.erl"},{line,352}]},{mod_last,get_last,2,[{file,"src/mod_last.erl"},{line,181}]},{mod_last,get_last_info,2,[{file,"src/mod_last.erl"},{line,248}]},{mod_admin_extra,get_last,2,[{file,"src/mod_admin_extra.erl"},{line,1382}]},{mod_http_api,handle2,4,[{file,"src/mod_http_api.erl"},{line,268}]},{mod_http_api,handle,4,[{file,"src/mod_http_api.erl"},{line,229}]}]`
I checked my ejabberd.yml `mod_last: {}` is added in the modules tag.
My ejabberd configuration:

```
hosts:
  - "faiqkhan-VirtualBox"

loglevel: 4
log_rotate_size: 10485760
log_rotate_count: 1

certfiles:
  - "/home/faiqkhan/ejabberd-20.07/conf/server.pem"

ca_file: "/home/faiqkhan/ejabberd-20.07/conf/cacert.pem"

listen:
  -
    port: 5222
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 262144
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    starttls_required: false
  -
    port: 5269
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
    max_stanza_size: 524288
  -
    port: 5443
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: false
    request_handlers:
      "/admin": ejabberd_web_admin
      "/api": mod_http_api
      "/bosh": mod_bosh
      "/captcha": ejabberd_captcha
      "/upload": mod_http_upload
      "/ws": ejabberd_http_ws
      "/oauth": ejabberd_oauth
  -
    port: 5280
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      "/admin": ejabberd_web_admin
  -
    port: 1883
    ip: "::"
    module: mod_mqtt
    backlog: 1000

s2s_use_starttls: optional

acl:
  local:
    user_regexp: ""
  loopback:
    ip:
      - 127.0.0.0/8
      - ::1/128
      - ::FFFF:127.0.0.1/128
      - ::FFFF:172.0.0.1/16
  admin:
    user:
      - "admin@faiqkhan-VirtualBox"
    ip:
      - ::FFFF:172.19.0.0/16
access_rules:
  local:
    allow: local
  c2s:
    deny: blocked
    allow: all
  announce:
    allow: admin
  configure:
    allow: admin
  muc_create:
    allow: local
  pubsub_createnode:
    allow: local
  trusted_network:
    allow: local

api_permissions:
  "console commands":
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
    who: all
    what: "*"
  "admin access":
    who:
      access:
        allow:
          acl: loopback
          acl: admin
      oauth:
        scope: "ejabberd:admin"
        access:
          allow:
            acl: loopback
            acl: admin
    what:
      - "*"
      - "!stop"
      - "!start"
  "public commands":
    who:
      ip: 127.0.0.1/8
    what:
      - status
      - connected_users_number

shaper:
  normal: 1000
  fast: 50000

shaper_rules:
  max_user_sessions: 10
  max_user_offline_messages:
    5000: admin
    100: all
  c2s_shaper:
    none: admin
    normal: all
  s2s_shaper: fast

max_fsm_queue: 10000

acme:
   contact: "mailto:admin@faiqkhan-VirtualBox"
   ca_url: "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"

allow_contrib_modules: true

modules:
  mod_stanza_ack: {}
  mod_http_offline: {}
  mod_adhoc: {}
  mod_admin_extra: {}
  mod_announce:
    access: announce
  mod_avatar: {}
  mod_blocking: {}
  mod_bosh: {}
  mod_caps: {}
  mod_carboncopy: {}
  mod_client_state: {}
  mod_configure: {}
  mod_disco: {}
  mod_fail2ban: {}
  mod_http_api: {}
  mod_http_upload:
    put_url: https://@HOST@:5443/upload
  mod_last: {}
  mod_mam:
    ## Mnesia is limited to 2GB, better to use an SQL backend
    ## For small servers SQLite is a good fit and is very easy
    ## to configure. Uncomment this when you have SQL configured:
    ## db_type: sql
    assume_mam_usage: true
    default: never
  mod_mqtt: {}
  mod_muc:
    access:
      - allow
    access_admin:
      - allow: admin
    access_create: muc_create
    access_persistent: muc_create
    access_mam:
      - allow
    default_room_options:
      allow_subscription: true  # enable MucSub
      mam: false
  mod_muc_admin: {}
  mod_offline:
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
  mod_ping: {}
  mod_privacy: {}
  mod_private: {}
  mod_proxy65:
    access: local
    max_connections: 5
  mod_pubsub:
    access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
    plugins:
      - flat
      - pep
    force_node_config:
      ## Avoid buggy clients to make their bookmarks public
      storage:bookmarks:
        access_model: whitelist
  mod_push: {}
  mod_push_keepalive: {}
  mod_register:
    ## Only accept registration requests from the "trusted"
    ## network (see access_rules section above).
    ## Think twice before enabling registration from any
    ## address. See the Jabber SPAM Manifesto for details:
    ## https://github.com/ge0rg/jabber-spam-fighting-manifesto
    ip_access: all
  mod_roster:
    versioning: true
  mod_s2s_dialback: {}
  mod_shared_roster: {}
  mod_stream_mgmt:
    resend_on_timeout: if_offline
  mod_vcard:
    search: true
  mod_vcard_xupdate: {}
  mod_version:
    show_os: false
```

Comment: If you have a problem using an API, show how you use that API.

Comment: I am using like this: `./ejabberdctl get_last 67456efc-be57-4cbd-a176-527de2dce19d@faiqkhan-virtualbox faiqkhan-VirtualBox`

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation of the get_last API call you want to use. It seems you are not providing the correct arguments:
https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/admin-api/#get-last

Comment: Yes. I already followed the document you mentioned here and use the same API you highlighted.

Comment: If this is what you use, then you are not following the documentation: ./ejabberdctl get_last 67456efc-be57-4cbd-a176-527de2dce19d@faiqkhan-virtualbox faiqkhan-VirtualBox

Comment: The API requires user name in string which is 67456efc-be57-4cbd-a176-527de2dce19d@faiqkhan-virtualbox and my host name is faiqkhan-virtualbox

Comment: I don't know how It is working now. I just restart my virtual machine and ejabberd server and the command worked for me. But when I set user name like this `67456efc-be57-4cbd-a176-527de2dce19d@faiqkhan-virtualbox and my hostname faiqkhan-virtualbox` it returns: NOT FOUND (at least give proper result.) and when I set a username like this: `67456efc-be57-4cbd-a176-527de2dce19d with the same hostname` command return expected result.

Comment: If the username is `abc`, and the server or host is `faiqkhan-virtualbox`, then the JabberID is `abc@faiqkhan-virtualbox`.